# How to retrieve icons of apps in iOS?

Tags: ios, icons, process

I am able to get all the processes that are running using the following code..

```
for (i = 0; i < nprocs;  i++) {
        printf("%5d\t%s\n",(int)procs[i].kp_proc.p_pid, procs[i].kp_proc.p_comm);
    }
```

I see some apps like `MobileSMS`, `Camera`, `MobileMail` and I would like to put their icons but I don't know how to retrieve them.. Any help with this will be appreciated..

Comment: Not sure if apple will allow you to operate outside your sandbox. But if you do not care, you can always try [UIImage imageNamed:]; and point to the image file.

Comment: @user1526474 did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to do this on a non-jailbroken phone.

Even if it was though, I don't think it would be the right thing to do. You should contact the makers of those apps and ask them if it would be OK to use their icon in your app. They might be happy for the extra exposure and would likely provide the artwork for you.

Comment: please look at the picture... http://iappsin.com/uploads/2011/07/monitor_your_idevice_with_activity_monitor_touch_2.jpg